# Windows hostfile using https?

Tags: https, dns, local, host

I'm trying to do a few mappings of my local network. so far with great success, but now im trying to access a part that is using http, and have so far not been having any success for that

Ive tried https://192.168.1.11 unifi

Is there a way to add https:// and ports
like https:192.168.1.11:8443 unifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host file exists only to map hostnames to IP addresses. It knows nothing of HTTP and ports which would be handled by the server running at the IP address you are pointing to.

To map the hostname `unifi` to `192.168.1.11` your entry would look something like:

`192.168.1.11   unifi www.unifi`

And you would access port `8443` via HTTPS by going to https://unifi:8443 assuming the server at that location is set up to handle the request.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Comment: Thought so, just hoped there was a way
Thanks